# PDF for use in app?

Tags: android, pdf, android-studio, drawable

I have a PDF that I want to be in the app I am creating. I know that I can convert the pdf to a drawable and set it as the background for the activity. The only problem with this is that the PDF has multiple pages and I do not know how to scroll through them. I was wondering if there was a way to scroll through drawables or what the best way is to set this up.

I am creating an app for school and the PDF that I want is a student handbook. Currently I have the app open the PDF in the browser and then download it but I would like it to open in-app?

Here is my current code for what happens when the button is pressed

```
public void startNewActivityHandbook (View view) {
    goToUrl ( "http://www.northglennhs.org/images/stories/NGHS_forms/2013-2014%20schedule.pdf");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the pdf as a drawable acting as a background to the activity then surround your layout with a scrollview so that you can scroll the pdf drawable as you are scrolling different pages.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/pdf_drawable">
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I tried that but I do not know how to create a group of drawables or something like that for it to scroll through. I tried to put the pdf into the drawables folders but it could not be read